# Unitest for function that handles exception

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a function that parses a xml string if there are invalid characters, the etree.parse raises parse error and my function handles that by decoding the string and encoding the string back. How do it test the part that handles the exception? It returns normal output for invalid data as for valid data.

```
def get_parse_tree(xml):
   try:
      tree = etree.parse(cStringIO.StringIO(xml))
   except etree.ParseError:
       clean_xml = xml.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore").encode("utf-8")
       tree = etree.parse(cStringIO.StringIO(clean_xml))
   except Exception as e:
       print e
  return tree
```

Comment: Mock out `etree.parse` to raise an exception? Note that in your final case (`Exception` but *not* a `ParseError`) your function doesn't work.

Comment: Don't "pretend" to handle an exception just by printing it. Log it (to standard error, not standard output), but immediately re-raise it with a bare `raise` statement.

Comment: @chepner If I am re raising it,  should i just remove that exception handler?

Comment: If *all* you do is re-raise it (`except Exception as e: raise`), then yes. Bare `raise` exists to let you take some action without claiming to fully handle the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unit test doesn't necessarily need to care which, if any, exception is raised by a bad input. Simply call the function with the bad input, and verify that either the expected "fixed" value is returned, or verify that an unrecoverable error occurs.

```
self.assertEqual(get_parse_tree("good input"), "good output one")
self.assertEqual(get_parse_tree("bad but recoverable input"), "good output two")
self.assertRaise(Exception, get_parse_tree, "bad, unrecoverable input")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `unittest` and `TestCase`, you can use [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)

```
class TestSuite(TestCase):

    def test_get_parse_tree(self):
        with self.assertRaises(etree.ParseError):
            # Force your error here
```